# What is "Serial Voting" & why was it selectively reversed?

Tags: support, reputation

Some time ago, I was editing my [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110856/political-bantering-puzzle) and suddenly saw the vote count move up. By the time I competed the edit, the vote count was back, which surprised me enough to accidentally not commit my edit.

Then I saw this in "Recent Reputation Changes":

[image: Three upvotes for an answer, one upvote for a question, and one serial upvoting reversal]

The 3 upvotes on my answer were by 3 users. Assuming that one of those users also upvoted my question, that would make 2 votes by the same user. Is this enough to be considered "Serial Voting"?
Why was it reversed against only my question rather than my answer, or even both?

At times, I have upvoted 3 or more items, without encountering this situation.  The help section has no mention about this.

Comment: Might be helpful to check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a recent widespread serial voting correction. (Perhaps there have been multiple waves. I am not privy to details.) See [a main-meta report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371020/1017231) and [more explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/1017231). Likely, someone had a script which automatically upvoted 40 random posts in a day to get a badge. Since this is not allowed it was all reversed. You must've had one post that got swept up.

Comment: I think , such Info should be broadcast automatically to all relevant Community users !

Comment: @Prem there is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371056/the-learn-more-explanation-for-voting-correction-does-not-cover-all-scenarios) to add information about this scenario into the "learn more" link shown if there is a voting correction in the reputation history